# jQuery datepicker runs only at first execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

My page loads **daily.js** this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.loadedJQuery = true;
    window.loadedJQueryUI = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pages/admin/daily.js"></script>
```

This is what **daily.js** contains (hugely simplified version):

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    $("#start-date, #end-date").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
};
```

this correctly makes a `datepicker` out of `start-date` and `end-date`, which look like this:

```
<label>
    Munkálatok időintervalluma: <input id="start-date" type="text"> - <input id="end-date" type="text">
</label>
```

So far so good. But upon some event, a popup window appears. To make sure that accordingly the Javascript related to it is correctly executed, I add an invisible `iframe` like this:

```
<iframe style="display: none;" onload="function loadJQuery() {window.loadedjQuery = document.createElement(&quot;script&quot;);window.loadedjQuery.src=&quot;/js/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js&quot;;window.loadedjQuery.onload = loadJQueryUI;document.head.appendChild(window.loadedjQuery);}function loadJQueryUI() {window.loadedJQueryUI = document.createElement(&quot;script&quot;);window.loadedJQueryUI.src=&quot;/js/lib/jquery-ui.js&quot;;window.loadedJQueryUI.onload = loadAddEditJob;document.head.appendChild(window.loadedJQueryUI);var link = document.createElement(&quot;link&quot;);link.rel = &quot;stylesheet&quot;;link.href = &quot;/css/jquery-ui.css&quot;;document.head.appendChild(link);}function loadAddEditJob() {window.loadedAddEditJob = document.createElement(&quot;script&quot;);window.loadedAddEditJob.src=&quot;/js/templates/AddEditJob.js&quot;;document.head.appendChild(window.loadedAddEditJob);}if (!window.loadedjQuery) {loadJQuery();} else if (!window.loadedJQueryUI) {loadJQueryUI();} else if (!loadedAddEditJob) {loadAddEditJob();}" "=""></iframe>
```

Inside my popup window, which is not inside an `iframe` I have this:

```
<input class="form-data" name="StartedDate" type="text" id="started-date" value="2018-07-29">
```

and this:

```
<input class="form-data" name="EndedDate" type="text" id="ended-date" value="2018-07-29">
```

and **AddEditJob.js** is loaded, which is looking like this (hugely simplified version):

```
$(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    $("#started-date, #ended-date").each(function() {
        if ((this.id === "started-date") && (!$(this).val())) {
            $(this).val(d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate());
        }
        $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
});
```

My problem is that `started-date` and `ended-date` will not work as one might expect a `datepicker` to work, namely, when I click inside them, nothing happens. No error message, nothing, although the `hasDatePicker` `class` is correctly added to them, as one might expect. If I avoid initializing my first datepickers as datepickers like

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //$("#start-date, #end-date").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
};
```

and open the popup window, then the items inside it are correctly initialized as datepickers and they work well. If I close the popup window and reopen it, even though everything inside was destroyed and recreated, my items will work correctly as datepickers.

My question is: How can I make sure that both the `datepicker` to be executed upon load and the one executed upon popup window showing would initialize all my datepickers correctly?

EDIT:

After intensively trying to solve the issue I did not manage to do it, so I created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1zk8mc7/9/).

HTML:

```
<label>
    Munkálatok időintervalluma: <input id="start-date" type="text"> - <input id="end-date" type="text">
</label>
<input class="form-data" name="StartedDate" type="text" id="started-date" value="2018-07-29">
<input class="form-data" name="EndedDate" type="text" id="ended-date" value="2018-07-29">
<button onclick="window.createIFrame();">
    Create Iframe
</button>
```

JS:

```
    $("#start-date, #end-date").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
window.test = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    $("#started-date, #ended-date").each(function() {
        if ((this.id === "started-date") && (!$(this).val())) {
            $(this).val(d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate());
        }
        $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
};
window.createIFrame = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<iframe style="display: none;" onload="console.log(window.test);window.test();"></iframe>';
}
```

All the four inputs should work as datepickers, but the third and fourth are not working like datepickers.

Comment: can you create demo in JSfiddle, so it would be easy to get the better understanding

Comment: @spankajd I would need a lot of time to write a JSFiddle for this purpose. I am rather spending that time to research and experiment. I might come up with an answer soon. So, instead of using JSFiddle, I would rather explain anything which was unclarified in my question.

Comment: You don't say how the popup is rendered/loaded.  There should be an event you can hook into, eg for bootstrap it would be `$("#mymodal").on("shown.bs.modal", function()...`

Comment: @spankajd I have added a JSFiddle

Comment: @freedomn-m It is a very simple click event which sends an AJAX request and puts the response into the DOM. Let's think agnostically about any HTML change in the document.

Comment: Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g1zk8mc7/13/

Comment: You say that, yet you've presented an XY problem.  You've not been able to set the datepickers so you've come up with a convoluted method using an iframe and then asked a question about that.  The real/source question is how to update datepickers after updating the HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m I needed to execute a Javascript to load my own scripts which were not needed before the popup, hence the iframe. The iframe has an onload which executes a Javascript code, which runs correctly and sets the datepickers correctly if datepickers were not set before.

Comment: If I simply put <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/templates/AddEditJob.js"></script> instead of my iframe, then it appears inside the structure, but it is not being loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could see in the above code and JSFeddle. Your updating DOM by `document.body.innerHTML += '<iframe style="display: none;" onload="console.log(window.test);window.test();"></iframe>';
}` code.

You need to reassign datepicker event to those input field.

or simply add below code after dom update.

```
$('.ui-datepicker').remove();
$("#start-date, #end-date").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

This is updated JSFeddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/g1zk8mc7/53/
Thanks